# Is there any way to find out how many items in a list view are showing?

Tags: android, listview, scroll, visible

I want to do a particular action on the items of the listview that the user can see without scrolling. Is there anyway to get the amount of items shown, or is there any other way of approaching this?

Comment: Check [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1549356/detecting-scroll-position-inside-a-listview-or-scrollview).

Comment: This is very similar to what I want, except for some reason, getLastVisiblePosition always returns -1. Do you know of any reason why it would?

Comment: When do you call the method getLastVisiblePosition()?

Comment: After I've populated my ListView. It's the last thing in the onCreate()

Comment: Mh I think this could be to early as at this moment Android hasn't finished arranging all View elements. So Android cannot yet tell you what the last visible position will be. I think you have to call the method some time after onResume() has finished.

Comment: Sorry, it is actually the last thing in the onResume already, and on a button click too. I just didn't think mentioning those would make a difference.

Comment: Mh when it is in onResume() it is still to early, but as you say it also doesn't work in an OnClickListener the reason for this behavior must be something else. An OnClickListener definitely doesn't get called before the view isn't ready.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

I dont know what exact is your requirement but to know the no list items that are currently visible

```
ListView.getFirstVisiblePosition();     
ListView.getLastVisiblePosition();
```

Comment: Do you know of any reason why getLastVisiblePosition would return -1?

Comment: if there is no item in in ListView

Comment: I have 10 hardcoded in, and I call getLastVisiblePosition after they are shown, but it still returns -1

Comment: check if getCount() method is returning correct value before calling for last item also post your xml here

Comment: @NotACleverMan the `ListView` must first be measured and laid-out. Set adapter and set `OnGlobalLayoutListener` to it's `ViewTreeObserver`. After `onGlobalLayout` event you can call these methods.

Answer (score 3):

You can find how many items of `listview` below:

```
int count = listview.getChildCount();
```

Answer (score 2):

Your `ListView` can implement `onScrollListener` where you can override its `onScroll` method. The method receives following arguments:

```
public void onScroll(AbsListView view, int firstVisibleItem, int visibleItemCount, int totalItemCount){}
```

Perhaps you can start from this.